# %files section in building rpm from source using Red Hat package Manager

Tags: redhat, rpm, package-management

I am creating customized rpm through source. I want to know what is the use of %files section.
These are the files that rpm will include in the package or it needs these files for rpm creation purpose? How to know which files should be listed under %files section and what is the exact path of these files?

Follwoing error is coming:

```
/bin/sh ../../libtool --mode=install ../../build/shtool install -c -m 644 libldap.la /usr/local/openldap-2.4.31-root/usr/lib
libtool: install: error: cannot install 'libldap.la' to a directory not ending in usr/local/lib
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1):

They enumerate the files and their corresponding ownership and permissions within the generated package. There is no fixed way to know which files should be listed within, but in general if you only generate one package then it will contain all files installed.

Comment: how to get the listing of installed files in order to mention in spec file?

Comment: Have you... even actually tried it out yet? Or are you just asking a bunch of theoretical questions?

Comment: Obviously, I have tried and getting errors if I am not mentioning these files.

Comment: So... then... mention them.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error details. May be this will be helpful in understanding problem. Thanks

Comment: That's not an error that has anything to do with `%files`; that's a plain old build error.

Comment: How can this build error be resolved?